# Como mandar array de dropzone.js a un controlador en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, php7, dropzone, dropzone.js

Hola amigos cuento con el siguiente código:

```
var arrayFiles = [];

$(".multimediaFisica").dropzone({

url: "/",
addRemoveLinks: true,
acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png",
maxFilesize: 2, //2mb
maxFiles: 10, //maximo 10 archivos
init: function () {

    this.on("addedfile", function (file) {

        arrayFiles.push(file);
        savearray();

    })

    this.on("removedfile", function (file) {

        var index = arrayFiles.indexOf(file);

        arrayFiles.splice(index, 1);

        savearray();
        console.log("arrayFiles", arrayFiles);

    })

 }

 })

 function savearray() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayFiles));
    $("#arrayimagenes").val(JSON.stringify(arrayFiles));
 }
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que el array que se genera con dropzone, guardarlo en un input de tipo HIDDEN, para pasar a enviar el formulario mediante un submit hacia un controlador y dentro de ese controlador descomponer el array para poder subirlas a una carpeta del proyecto, hasta ahora no he podido hacer lo que menciono, ya tengo otro proyecto que lo hago mediante ajax y ahí va todo perfecto, pero esta ocasión me pidieron hacerlo de la primer manera que les comente, hay alguien que me pueda ayudar porfavor...

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que necesitas hacer es acceder al array dentro del componente del dropzone. 
El primer paso es colocar un array vacio que es el que terminaras mandando a tu controlador

```
var arrayFiles = []; //El que se envia al controlador.
```

Despues declaras tu dropzone, tal cual lo tienes. Luego es acceder a los objetos(files) del dropzone en tu submit.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
     for (var i = 0; i < $(".multimediaFisica").dropzone.files.length; i++) {
        arrayFiles .push($(".multimediaFisica").dropzone.files[i]);
    }
    //Después de completar el json, le agregas el array, tal cual lo esperas recibir 
    en tu controlador.  
    var json = //todo lo que llevarás al controlador.
    json.images = arrayFiles

});
```

Otra opcion es descomponer los archivos del array con las propiedades que esperas recibir en tu controlador. Y al momento de guardarlo solo necesitas mandarlo a una carpeta dentro del directorio de tu proyecto.